# Error while trying to retrieve a deleted file in svn

Tags: svn

I am trying to look at the content of a file that has been deleted in svn. The svn log shows something like the following entry:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r12503 | alex| 2014-11-04 17:53:50 +0100 (Tue, 04 Nov 2014) | 3 lines
Changed paths:
   D XXX/trunk/config_jenkins.bat
```

which shows me the file in question has been deleted at revision 12503. I am trying to look at the content of this file at revision 12502 like this:

```
svn cat -r 12502 $REPO/trunk/config_jenkins.bat@12502
```

which results in the following error:

```
svn: warning: W160013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'XXX/trunk/config_jenkins.bat'
svn: E200009: Could not cat all targets because some targets don't exist
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
```

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Was `12502` definitely the last version of the deleted file? If so, just try this:

`svn cat url/of/file@12502`

Comment: I only can say it has been deleted at revision 12503 (as shown). So it should be present at revision 12502, or not? Using your suggestion gives the same error.

Comment: Switching to the revision in question using the `svn switch` is a choice too. You may want to give that a try.

Comment: switch: 'svn: E195019: Redirect cycle detected for URL 'XXX/tas/trunk'
'